# PHP String operator - combined with Function()

Tags: php, function, operators

I would like to combine the usage of a function(), and echo it with a string operator.

The reason for this usage is that I'm building a html/php form what contains multiple pull down menus, where only the name is different. 
And I use the string operator for my SQL query with while/if/else statements.

Function:

```
function telling($setname) 
    {
        echo "<select name=".$setname.">";
        foreach (range(0, 35) as $number) 
        {               
                echo "<option value=".$number.">".$number."</option>\r\n";  
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
```

And for the output:

```
$output "";
$output .= "<form>";
telling("set1_1");
$output .= "  -  ";
telling("set1_2");
....
$output .= "</form>";
echo $output;
```

I do get the pulldown menu on the site, but on a different part on the site as intended. 
Do you guys know how to combine my methods.

Comment: what exactly result you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function telling($setname) 
{
    $html = "<select name=".$setname.">";
    foreach (range(0, 35) as $number) 
    {               
            $html .= "<option value=".$number.">".$number."</option>\r\n";  
    }
    $html .= "</select>";
    return $html;
}
```

and also change

```
$output = "";
$output .= "<form>";
$output .= telling("set1_1");
$output .= "  -  ";
$output .= telling("set1_2");
....
$output .= "</form>";
echo $output;
```

Comment: check now i just change it